# Java define method which returns same value for 2 consecutive numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to define a method (basically a hashcode) which returns same value for 2 consecutive number.

```
  public int someMethod(int x) {

    // do something with x which return same value for 2 consecutive number
    // x , x-1 OR x, x+1

    }
```

I tried this -

```
public int someMethod(int d) {
        return (int) (((float)d / 3) + 0.5);
}
```

but its not working for all values. like it is able to generate same value for 3 & 4 but not for 4 & 5. it should return same value for all integer which have 1 difference. May be i need a method who is not able to generate same values but the best to generate same values.

Comment: By definition your function will return the same value for EVERY number. Since x is consecutive to x+1, and x+1 is consecutive to x+2...

Comment: If you want x-1, x , x+1 to have the same value for every x, you need a **constant** function.

Comment: `public int someMethod(int x) { return x/2;}` will return the same result for any x, x+1 where x is an even number (int).

Comment: and what if x is odd?

Comment: alfasin is performing integer division which discards any remainder. So when you do `3 / 2` you get `1`.

Comment: vikingsteve - it should not generate the same number for x-1 & x what it is generating for x & x+1. so it will not return the same value for EVERY number.

Answer (score 3):

You can just strip the lowest bit of the number, which varies between odd and even numbers. This will return what you want:

```
public int someMethod(int x) {
    // Since you want 3 and 4 to match, you add one here so they become 4 and 5
    x++;

    return x >> 1;
}
```

This works because binary numbers are represented as sequences of ones and zeros. When you strip the lowest bit you reduce the numbers that can be represented by half. Some examples might help:

- 010 = 2
- 011 = 3
- 100 = 4
- 101 = 5

When the last digit is removed:

- 01
- 01
- 10
- 10

As alfasin points out this is equivalent to performing an integer division by two, which will strip any remainder.

Comment: Which is basically the same as returning `x/2` ;)

Comment: No, it rounds down so 1799 is paired with 1798. If you need those numbers to have the same output then just add one before calling the method.

Comment: I have updated the answer to make 3 & 4 have the same result (and 1799 & 1800).

Comment: still this solution is not generic .. it does not work for 4 & 5

Comment: You have stated in your question that you want 3 & 4 to return the same value, but that the value for 4 & 5 should be different. This returns that. If you want to return the same value for 3, 4 and 5 then that is a different problem.

Comment: Basically if *any* two consecutive numbers must return the same value then your method will return the same value for all numbers since they are all consecutive directly or indirectly.

Comment: what would be solution if i want to generate same value for a set 3  4  5 ?

Comment: `public int someMethod(int x) { return 0; }`. Fundamentally you have a method that takes *one* number, `X`. You want it to return the same value as that `X - 1` *and* `X + 1`. When you consider that the same condition must hold for `X + 1` you realise that the return value of `X` must be the same as the return value of `X + 2` and by induction every single integer. You need to think about your problem more. I now realise you are not the original question asker :)

Comment: If you wanted to do it in sets of 3 then you could just do an integer division by three: `public int someMethod(int x) { return x / 3; }`. This will return the same value for 3, 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem maybe add a new parameter to resolve. Maybe like this -

```
public int someMethod(int x, int default){
    if(x - default == 1 || x - default = -1){
        return x;
    }
}
```

But I have't use some method like that...

Comment: I am over riding a hash code method. what is default here

Answer (score 0):

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... 10_000, 10_001 all of these are the consecutive numbers. Will you pass only 2 of them or some of them. Your question is not clear.

i.e: passing (3, 4) then (4, 5). Do you wish the same results for these sets, because of common number "4".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(someMethod(3, 4));
    System.out.println(someMethod(5, 4));
    System.out.println(someMethod(6, 4));

}

/**
 * if value and common are not consecutive return value; 
 * 
 * @param value
 * @param common
 * @return
 */
public static int someMethod(int value, int common) {

    int x = value - common;

    if (x == 1 || x == -1)
        return common;

    return value;
}
```

console result: 
4
4
6